# Microsoft Graph API - Expanding versions for recently accessed files gives error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the Microsoft Graph API to get files recently accessed by a user. Versions is a relationship of the response type, as per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships).

However, when I try to add an expand param to include versions as well, I get an error.

This is the query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?$expand=versions
```

And I get a `generalException` response with this error message:

```
An unspecified error has occurred.
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: I was also able to see the same error as you said. But as a work around you can get the driveItem id and use **/me/drive/items/{item-id}/versions** to each driveItem and get the versions.

Comment: Thanks @Shiva-MSFTIdentity - this is what I ended up doing. It's not ideal because I have to make an additional request for each file, but works for now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Utkarsh. Moving this to answer.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also able to reproduce your issue as you said. But as a work around you can use the same `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent` and get the recent driveItem objects and pull the driveItem Ids individually and make requests individually. You can use either one of the below calls.

1. You can get the data with other properties of the driveItem.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01252UHI5DGSKWGHIUXBD3GPQWY7UT7TVN?$expand=versions`

2. If you want to get only versions you can use the below query.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01252UHI5DGSKWGHIUXBD3GPQWY7UT7TVN/versions`